# Change PDF cache rate or a solution to download vs open PDF in new window?

Tags: .htaccess, caching, pdf, browser-cache

I have done lots of searching on here and applied a few of the methods mentioned without any luck.

My problem is a site I manage, the client uploads a new PDF under the same file name on a weekly basis. The problem is people are trying to download this, and lots are complaining that its loading the past weeks PDF. This is due to browser caching because when I tell them to clear their cache everything is OK.

I have two possible solutions:

1) Force the PDF file to download, vs opening in a new window. Now I have tried all sorts of these htaccess tweaks but none seem to work on IE9 or Safari.

2) Change the cache rate somehow, so that the cache rate for PDF files only lasts a minute, I have no idea how this could be done or if its even possible?

Does anyone have any solutions, rather then the obvious of just chaining the file name each time? The reason we dont do this is she wants to upload the PDFs on her own and not have to worry about editing the HTML file link.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Add a cache-buster query string? `http://example.com/whatever.pdf?random_value_here`. PDFs will ignore the query string, and browsers will think it's a "new" url each time, skipping the cache completely. The cache-buster value can be added trivially via javascript at document load, if need be.

Comment: we usually save the path to it in a database. we have 2 columns - one for the server name and one for the client name. The client name can be the same all the time but the server name is always unique (usually based on the date). so you open the pdf from the page with the server name and then change its name to the client name for the user.

Comment: @MarcB interesting, but wont eventually if the random value stays the same the same problem occur? The thing is the client does not want to go into the HTML files to change the link, just keep reuploading the PDF.

Comment: hence using JS to do it. e.g. `<a id="pdflink" href="yourfile.pdf">click</a><script>document.getElementById('pdflink').add_cache_buster_to_href();</script>` kind of thing.

Comment: @MarcB this makes sense, the idea, but Im still unsure of how to use this, is there a tutorial that you know of?

Comment: Found a script to do this but no idea if its working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FilesMatch` container and `mod_headers` to accomplish the prevention of cache in all browsers, clients, and proxies:

```
<FilesMatch ".pdf$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: The site is in HMTL. Very basic website. I also get a "Internal Server Error 500" when adding your above code to my htacess.

Comment: Weird indeed - I do not get an error on my testing server... It could only be doing that because the `FilesMatch` container is not supported on your server, which shouldn't be the case (I've never heard of such an issue).

Comment: It worked now, I added it before the rest of the stuff in my .htaccess at the top and its fine now :)

Comment: And is it definitely serving up a fresh copy every time?

Comment: Apparently not, they tried updating some other PDFs and it did not work, they kept seeing the old version?! Any other ideas? They are on IE.  Thanks @mike-anthony

Comment: You say in your comments above that you're using a database. But here you say you're using basic HTML. Databases need a scripting language in order to function, unless you're doing everything manually. Could you send me the address of the site so I can take a look?